# Defining default format for number input in C

Tags: c, validation, input

I am interested if  there is any way to set default way to input numbers in C, for example xxxx.xx, like  valid number for this example would be 1.00 or 1234.00, something like that.

I have searched for this in many sites, but didn't find anything useful.

I know its rather simple task, but I am new for **C** so it gives me trouble :D

Comment: How are you "inputting" these numbers?  gets()or getchr() from stdin, or something else?...

Comment: I think you'd like to use `setlocale("C")`. There isn't realy much else, outside maybe some tweaks in scanf

Comment: I thought `setlocale()` is for encoding and localization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly `scanf()` may be what you're looking for.

[scanf() C reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)

With that function you can define the format of the input from `stdin`.

```
float f;
scanf ("%f",&f);
```

> **type:** e,E,f,g,G
>   **Floating point:** Decimal number containing a decimal point, optionally
>   preceded by a + or - sign and optionally folowed by the e or E
>   character and a decimal number. Two examples of valid entries are
>   -**732.103** and 7.12e4